# How to turn off source formatter in Delphi 2010 for sections of code?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

something like Jedi Code format:

```
//jcf:format=off
.
.
.
//jcf:format=on
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such option for the builtin formatter.

Just for the record: The code formatter in my experimental GExperts Version uses

```
{(*}
...
{*)}
```

for this purpose. Since it does not support some of the later Delphi language extensions like subtypes, it is necessary to use it in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without help from a delphi addon. There is no such option in Delphi at all.